# dismissviewcontrolleranimated not smooth

Tags: ios, uianimation

I have a `viewcontroller` and `childView` add the `viewcontroller`.

if the childView add animation and `stratAinmation`:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

Question:

system animation (page goes down) not smooth when`dismissviewcontrolleranimated`

if the childView add animation but don't stratAinmation:

system animation is very smooth when`dismissviewcontrolleranimated`

My plan:

I try`childView`removeAllAnimation when `viewWillDisappear`，the animation not smooth too.

help me,thanks.

Comment: In the completion block, call `dismissviewcontrolleranimated`.

Comment: @KudoCC the Animation is an infinite loop,`dismissviewcontrolleranimated` when user clicked back button.

Comment: How about `removeAllAnimation` before call `dismissviewcontrolleranimated` ?

Comment: @KudoCC at first,i think `viewcontroller`have some animation when `dismissviewcontrolleranimated` cause not smooth,so i `removeAllAnimation `.